# Java Date to milliseconds

Tags: java, date, time, amazon-web-services

I'm storing messages from an amazon cloud and ordering them by their timestamp in a sorted map.

I am parsing the timestamp from the cloud with the following code:

```
Date timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(time);
```

and then I am storing in them in a sorted map with the key being the date.
The issue is that the date only comes down to seconds precision.
I can have several messages sent in 1 second, so I need them to be ordered with millisecond precision. Is there a data structure that allows this?

Comment: Your format says `SSS` so millis must be there

Comment: If `time` contains UTC timezone (`Z`), use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. `Z` will *grab* `Z` as well as e.g., `+0100`

Comment: please print out timestamp.getTime()

Comment: Could you give an example of a value of time `time` that you would use?  Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well as long as your source has a higher resolution than 1 second. Looks like that from the pattern, but you haven't shown us any input example.

`Date` is just a wrapper around a `long` milliseconds since 1970-01-01. So you have that already. `Date.getTime()` will return that, with millisecond precision.

Why would you think that Date only has one second precision? `Date.compareTo(Date anotherDate)` compares on a millisecond level.
So your SortedMap should work fine unless you are doing something strange.

Comment: I thought that it wasnt able to as i wasnt able to get the milliseconds or set them. But you are right. Thanks for that. The error was coming from the fact that i was consuming messages at the rate they were coming in. This meant that the time wasnt being used properly. Fixed it by waiting 350 milliseconds then consuming from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have done this, but you can create your own comparator and use that.

As a side note, depending on your applications setup you may want to be careful with how you use [SimpleDateFormat](http://karul.org/blog/2012/01/thread-safety-issues-with-java-simpledateformat-clas/), there are some issues with it.

Comment: Your link is dead. (This is why link-only answers are bad.)  Would you care to elaborate on the "issues with SimpleDateFormat"?

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I am providing the modern answer: use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. First of all because it is so much nicer to work with than the old date and time classes like `Date` and (oh, horrors) `SimpleDateFormat`, which are poorly designed. We’re fortunate that they are long outdated. An added advantage is: Your date-time string is in ISO 8601 format, and the classes of java.time parse this format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

```
    String stringFromCloud = "2014-06-14T08:55:56.789Z";
    Instant timestamp = Instant.parse(stringFromCloud);
    System.out.println("Parsed timestamp: " + timestamp);
```

Output:

> Parsed timestamp: 2014-06-14T08:55:56.789Z

Now it’s clear to see that the string has been parsed with full millisecond precision (`Instant` can parse with nanosecond precision, up to 9 decimals on the seconds). `Instant` objects will work fine as keys for your `SortedMap`.

Corner case: if the fraction of seconds i 0, it is not printed.

```
    String stringFromCloud = "2014-06-14T08:56:59.000Z";
```

> Parsed timestamp: 2014-06-14T08:56:59Z

You will need to trust that when no fraction is printed, it is because it is 0. The `Instant` will still work nicely for your purpose, being sorted before instants with fraction .001, .002, etc.

### What went wrong in your parsing?

First, you’ve got a problem that is much worse than missing milliseconds: You are parsing into the wrong time zone. The trailing `Z` in your incoming string is a UTC offset of 0 and needs to be parsed as such. What happened in your code was that `SimpleDateFormat` used the time zone setting of your JVM instead of UTC, giving rise to an error of up to 14 hours. In most cases your sorting would still be correct. Around transition from summer time (DST) in your local time zone the time would be ambiguous and parsing may therefore be incorrect leading to wrong sort order.

As the Mattias Isegran Bergander says in his answer, parsing of milliseconds should work in your code. The reason why you didn’t think so is probably because just a minor one of the many design problems with the old `Date` class: even though internally it has millisecond precision, its `toString` method only prints seconds, it leaves out the milliseconds.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)